# JdbcTemplate - Como realizar commit e rollback?

Tags: java, oracle, spring

eu estou trabalhando com uma aplicação Desktop e utilizo o spring para realizar meus inserts no banco.

O objeto que estou utilizando é o JdbcTemplate, que tem o datasource encapsulado dentro de dele. Eu gostaria de saber, como iniciar novas transactions com o JdbcTemplate e como posso dar commit e rollback para uma transaction usando esse objeto.

Eu tentei utilizar a annotation @Transactional, mas ela parece não funcionar...

Na verdade, eu nao entendi muito bem como ela funciona... ela reverte o commit?

O que tenho tentado :

```
 @Transactional(rollingbackFor = Exception.class,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void Testing(){
    jdbcTemplate.exec("Insert into table Acess_Level(IdLevel,Description) values(1,'Admin')");
    jdbcTemplate.exec("Insert into table Acess_Level(IdLevel,Description) values(STRING,'Admin')");
 }
```

Comment: O que você tem tentado até então? Algum erro problema? Considere incluir o que você está tentando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ativando AOP

Uma das coisas que confunde no uso de anotações é que muitas vezes você precisa configurar o seu framework para que elas funcionem corretamente.

Veja, para o Spring conseguir interceptar a chamada ao método para então demarcar uma transação, ele usa um tipo de Programação Orientada a Aspectos.

Para ativar isso no Spring, você precisa primeiro definir um `TransactionManager`, por exemplo:

```
<bean id="myTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" 
      scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Depois, definir a configuração para ativar AOP no Spring:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
```

Se você usa Spring Boot ou configuração via classes, basta colocar as configurações equivalentes na sua classe de configuração. Veja a [documentação aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj).

## `TransactionTemplate`

A anotação não é a única maneira de usar transações. A versão programática de demarcar um bloco transacional com Spring é usando o `TransactionTemplate`.

Na [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic) tem um exemplo bem simples, onde basta injetar o `TransactionManager` e instanciar o objeto de transação:

```
public class SimpleService implements Service {

    // single TransactionTemplate shared amongst all methods in this instance
    private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    // use constructor-injection to supply the PlatformTransactionManager
    public SimpleService(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        Assert.notNull(transactionManager, "The ''transactionManager'' argument must not be null.");
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    public Object someServiceMethod() {
        return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
            // the code in this method executes in a transactional context
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                updateOperation1();
                return resultOfUpdateOperation2();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza a annotation `@Transactional`, você está falando que aquele componente vai ter ações de conexão com o banco de dados.

Agora sobre os atributos que compõem a annotation, eles irão ditar o comportamento da annotation.

Para maiores esclarecimentos sobre o `@Transactional`, dê uma conferida [aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api//org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) na documentação oficial (está em inglês).

No seu caso, acredito que o seguinte trecho de código esteja com algum problema.

```
@Transactional(rollingbackFor = Exception.class,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Tente alterar a assinatura da annotation para:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Sobre o funcionamento do `@Transactional`, ele só irá efetuar um rollback caso você especifique algum comportamento (como uma Exception) no `rollbackFor`.

No mais, espero ter sido capaz de esclarecer alguns pontos acerca dessa annotation.